# Convert each first item of sublist to dictionary key but first items are redundant

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I have a nested list like this:

```
nested_lst = [['Specie_1', "['GAT', 'GAC']", '[1.09, 0.95]'], ['Specie_1', "['TCT', 'TCG', 'TCA', 'TCC', 'AGC', 'AGT']", '[0.62, 0.50, 0.93, 0.59, 2.33, 0.96]'],['Specie_2', "['GAT', 'GAC']", '[1.03, 0.96]'], ['Specie_2', "['TCT', 'TCG', 'TCA', 'TCC', 'AGC', 'AGT']", '[0.66, 0.54, 0.91, 0.58, 2.39, 0.97]']
```

And I would like to convert this list into a nested dictionary of this frame:

```
{{Specie_1 : [GAT : 1.09], [GAC : 0.95], [TCT : 0.62], [TCG : 0.50], [TCA : 0.93], [TCC : 0.59], [AGC : 2.33], [AGT : 0.96]}
{Specie_2 : [GAT : 1.03], [GAC : 0.96], [TCT : 0.66], [TCG : 0.54], [TCA : 0.91], [TCC : 0.58], [AGC : 2.29], [AGT : 0.97]}}
```

The goal is to make a dataframe like this (using python) :

```
        Specie_1     Specie_2
GAT         1.09         1.03
GAC         0.95         0.96
TCT         0.62         0.66
TCG         0.50         0.54
TCA         0.93         0.91
TCC         0.59         0.58
AGC         2.33         2.29
AGT         0.96         0.97
```

I think I can achieve that by converting the nested list into a nested dictionary - but maybe I'm wrong and it's not what I should do to make this dataframe.
So I tried to get first items of each sublist (Specie_1 and Specie_2) as keys but those first items are redundant, as well as other items like "[GAT, GAC]" etc, so it doesn't work. Another difficulty is that I would like to keep this order.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that the `nested_list` is formatted a bit differently - so it is a valid python list.

You can use the `from_dict` method to create DataFrame [see documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

Then the solution could look like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

nested_lst = [
    ['Specie_1', ['GAT', 'GAC'], [1.09, 0.95]], 
    ['Specie_1', ['TCT', 'TCG', 'TCA', 'TCC', 'AGC', 'AGT'], [0.62, 0.50, 0.93, 0.59, 2.33, 0.96]],
    ['Specie_2', ['GAT', 'GAC'], [1.03, 0.96]], 
    ['Specie_2', ['TCT', 'TCG', 'TCA', 'TCC', 'AGC', 'AGT'], [0.66, 0.54, 0.91, 0.58, 2.39, 0.97]]
    ]

data_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for record in nested_lst:
    column, indicies, values = record
    for index, value in zip(indicies, values):
        data_dict[index][column] = value

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict, orient="index")
```

Basically, use the three-letter values as a keys for the dictionary (and subsequently as an index in dataframe). And the `specie_*` as a key in nested dictionary => so it is used as a column in dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply @Minarth. I followed your advice but it seems the way I did my nested_list is wrong because it didn't work. I actually have a tabulated file like:

```
Specie_1    ['GAT', 'GAC']    [1.09, 0.95]
Specie_1    ['TCT', 'TCG', 'TCA', 'TCC', 'AGC', 'AGT']    [0.62, 0.50, 0.93, 0.59, 2.33, 0.96]
Specie_2    ['GAT', 'GAC']    [1.03, 0.96]`
Specie_2    ['TCT', 'TCG', 'TCA', 'TCC', 'AGC', 'AGT']    [0.66, 0.54, 0.91, 0.58, 2.39, 0.97]
```

And thought this line could do a correct nested list: `nested_list = [l.rstrip('\n').split('\t') for l in f1.readlines()]`
I tried other code lines from other topics that convert the file content into a nested dictionary but it doesn't work with my data.

Comment: I suggest you edit most of this back into the question, as further context of how you got the data you have.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this ?

```
from collections import defaultdict,ChainMap
import ast

result = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(nested_lst)):
    result[nested_lst[i][0]].append(dict(zip(ast.literal_eval(nested_lst[i][1]), ast.literal_eval(nested_lst[i][2]))))

for key,val in result.items():
    result[key]= (dict(ChainMap(*val)))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

**Output**

```
     Specie_1  Specie_2
TCT      0.62      0.66
TCG      0.50      0.54
TCA      0.93      0.91
TCC      0.59      0.58
AGC      2.33      2.39
AGT      0.96      0.97
GAT      1.09      1.03
GAC      0.95      0.96
```

Comment: Hi, thank you it worked. But is it possible to keep the order of the first column ? Like in my example, GAT as first line of the first column, then GAC, below TCT, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to do a bit more work on input. Fortunately `eval` will handle a lot of it. Using the text you supplied (with amendments for your file access in comments)

```py
from collections import defaultdict

linedata = '''Specie_1    ['GAT', 'GAC']    [1.09, 0.95]
Specie_1    ['TCT', 'TCG', 'TCA', 'TCC', 'AGC', 'AGT']    [0.62, 0.50, 0.93, 0.59, 2.33, 0.96]
Specie_2    ['GAT', 'GAC']    [1.03, 0.96]
Specie_2    ['TCT', 'TCG', 'TCA', 'TCC', 'AGC', 'AGT']    [0.66, 0.54, 0.91, 0.58, 2.39, 0.97]'''.split('\n')

spec = defaultdict(dict)
for ln in linedata:          # in fl.readlines():
    elmts = ln.split('   ')  # ln.split('\t')
    spval = elmts[0].strip()
    codonrate = zip(eval(elmts[1]),eval(elmts[2]))
    spec[spval].update(codonrate)

print(*(i for i in spec.items()),sep='\n') # just to show what we collected here
```

Output (formatted a little; `spec` is actually a `dict` of `dict`s):

```
('Specie_1', {'GAT': 1.09, 'GAC': 0.95, 'TCT': 0.62, 'TCG': 0.5, 'TCA': 0.93, 'TCC': 0.59, 'AGC': 2.33, 'AGT': 0.96})
('Specie_2', {'GAT': 1.03, 'GAC': 0.96, 'TCT': 0.66, 'TCG': 0.54, 'TCA': 0.91, 'TCC': 0.58, 'AGC': 2.39, 'AGT': 0.97})
```

Answer (score 0):

try to collect the data into a default dict, after this the dataframe is easy to create

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

nested_lst = [['Specie_1', "['GAT', 'GAC']", '[1.09, 0.95]'], ['Specie_1', "['TCT', 'TCG', 'TCA', 'TCC', 'AGC', 'AGT']", '[0.62, 0.50, 0.93, 0.59, 2.33, 0.96]'],['Specie_2', "['GAT', 'GAC']", '[1.03, 0.96]'], ['Specie_2', "['TCT', 'TCG', 'TCA', 'TCC', 'AGC', 'AGT']", '[0.66, 0.54, 0.91, 0.58, 2.39, 0.97]']]

dd=defaultdict(lambda: dict(k=[], v=[]))
for a,b,c in nested_lst:
    dd[a]['k']+=eval(b)
    dd[a]['v']+=eval(c)

print(pd.DataFrame({'Specie_1':dd['Specie_1']['v'], 'Specie_2':dd['Specie_2']['v']},index=dd['Specie_1']['k']))

    Specie_1    Specie_2
GAT     1.09    1.03
GAC     0.95    0.96
TCT     0.62    0.66
TCG     0.50    0.54
TCA     0.93    0.91
TCC     0.59    0.58
AGC     2.33    2.39
AGT     0.96    0.97
```